# Extending Riemann's zeta function to $0<s<1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

This is in reference to baby Rudin's Ch 6 exer 16:

He defines there $\zeta(s)=\sum_1^\infty\frac1{n^s}$ for $1<s<\infty$, and then asks to show that $$\zeta(s)=\frac s{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty \frac{x-[x]}{x^{s+1}}\,dx,$$ but he also asks to

> show that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x-[x]}{x^{s+1}}\,dx$$ converges for $0<s<1$ as well.

**My try:**

$$\begin{align}
\int_i^{i+1}\frac{x-[x]}{x^{s+1}}\,dx &= \int_i^{i+1}\frac{x-i}{x^{s+1}}\,dx\\
&= \int_i^{i+1}\frac{x}{x^{s+1}}\,dx-i\int_i^{i+1}\frac{1}{x^{s+1}}\,dx\\
&=\frac{(i+1)^{1-s}}{1-s}-\frac{i^{1-s}}{1-s}-i\left(\frac1{si^s}-\frac1{s(i+1)^s}\right).
\end{align}$$

How to show that $$\sum_1^\infty\left\{\frac{(i+1)^{1-s}}{1-s}-\frac{i^{1-s}}{1-s}-i\left(\frac1{si^s}-\frac1{s(i+1)^s}\right)\right\}$$ indeed converges for $0<s<1$?

Comment: Observe that $\;0\le x-\lfloor x\rfloor \le 1\;$ and you get the convergence of the integral at once. Why would you want to do integrals between $\;i\;$ and $\;i+1\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, oh! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fact that $0\leq x-[x]\leq1$ immediately leads to absolute convergence:
$$
\int_1^N\frac{x-[x]}{x^{s+1}}dx
\leq
\int_1^N\frac{dx}{x^{s+1}}
=\frac1{sx^{s}}\Big|_N^1\leq\frac1s.
$$

Comment: Nitpick: the integral's value must have a minus sign...and that's the reason why absolute value must be used.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't see it, I reversed the limits after integration.

Comment: Indeed you did, I didn't see that. Thanx.